# How do you say "He does do that" or "He does have that" in German?

Tags: translation

How do you say "He does do that" or "He does have that" in German?

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to know about the amplification introduced by the additional *do*. This is expressed with adverbs meaning *really* in German, or by introducing the sentence with a *Ja, …*.

*He does do/have that.*

> Das macht/hat er *wirklich/tatsächlich*.
>
> Ja, das macht/hat er.

You could even leave out that *Ja, …*, and only rely on the word order.

> **Das** macht er. *(focuses on das, an action supplement to machen)*
>
> **Er** macht das. *(neutral, focuses on er)*

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to clear up any doubt then **doch** expresses **do/does**

> Das macht er doch
>   Das hat er doch